# How would I make a gif jump, while implementing gravity and a ground y-variable?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, uigravitybehavior

[CatBus Code Link](https://editor.p5js.org/petersenirs/sketches/DGKS_RAaF)

I'm trying to make my gif "jump", while also coming back to rest at a y value of 730. No more, no less. It would work to the same extent as the Dinosaur game, when the wifi is out. I'd like to include a gravity function as well. I'm not sure how to do that. (I'm VERY new to coding.) Any tips?

[Code is below]

```
let img;    //background
var bgImg;    //also the background
var x1 = 0;
var x2;

var scrollSpeed = 4;  //how fast background is

let bing;   //for music

let cat = {   //coordinates for catbus
  x:70,
  y:730
}
  
var mode;  //determines whether the game has started


function preload() {
  bgImg = loadImage("backgwound.png");  //importing background

  bing=loadSound('catbus theme song.mp3');  //importing music

}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);   //canvas size

  img = loadImage("backgwound.png"); //background in

  x2 = width;

bing.loop()  //loops the music
  
  catGif=createImg("catgif.gif")    //creates catbus
  catGif. position(cat.x, cat.y)    //creates position
  catGif. size(270,100)             //creates how big
  
  mode = 0;                         //game start
  textSize(50);                     //text size
  
}

function draw() {

  let time = frameCount;        //start background loop

  image(img, 0 - time, 0);

  image(bgImg, x1, 2, width, height);
  image(bgImg, x2, 2, width, height);

  x1 -= scrollSpeed;
  x2 -= scrollSpeed;

  if (x1 <= -width) {
    x1 = width;
  }
  if (x2 <= -width) {
    x2 = width;
  }                       //end background loop

  
  fill("white")              //text colour
 if(mode==0){ 
  text('Press SPACE to start the game.',150,500);     //what text to type
 }  

  if(mode==0){
  text('CATBUS BIZZARE ADVENTURE',135,450)    //what text to type
  
  }
    
}


function pickRandom() {
  x = random(20, width - 20);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your [p5.js sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/YnF1Rwouf) to point you in the right direction.

I've introduced a few variables that are defined at the top of your code before setup:

```
let gravity = 0.1;
let velocity = 0;
let upForce = 3;

let startY = 730;
let startX = 70;
...
```

You can tweak these numbers to fit your game. But the basic premise here is that each frame we add the velocity to the `cat.y` and the `velocity` is incremented each frame by the `gravity`:

```js
 cat.y = cat.y + velocity;
 velocity = velocity + gravity;
```

However, there's a caveat, we don't want to add the velocity to the `cat.y` if the cat is at its `startY`, as `startY` is the grass:

```
if (cat.y > startY) {
  velocity = 0;
  cat.y = startY;
}

catGif.position(cat.x, cat.y); // reposition the gif
```

And lastly, when you hit spacebar, jump!
(And get rid of the starting screen)

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 32) {
    //spacebar
    mode = 1;
    velocity -= upForce;
  }
}
```